# Ace Editor - ready ONLY variables

Tags: javascript, json, editor, text-editor, ace-editor

I'm using Ace Editor and I'd like to apply readyOnly for variables only (JSON).
For example, in this case, the user CANNOT edit variables "number" and "text" but he CAN edit values "10" and "my text":

> ```
>  {
>     "number": 10,
>     "text": "my text"
>   }
> ```

I tried using this code:

```
var Range = window.ace.require('ace/range').Range
let range = new Range(1, 4, 4, 10);
const markerId = session.addMarker(range, "readonly-highlight");
editor.keyBinding.addKeyboardHandler(                                                      handleKeyboard : function(data, hash, keyString, keyCode, event) {
if (hash === -1 || (keyCode <= 40 && keyCode >= 37)) return false;
if (intersects(range)) {
return {command:"null", passEvent:false};
    }
   }
 });
 before(editor, 'onPaste', preventReadonly);
 before(editor, 'onCut',   preventReadonly);
 range.start  = session.doc.createAnchor(range.start);
 range.end    = session.doc.createAnchor(range.end);
 range.end.$insertRight = true;
 function before(obj, method, wrapper) {
   var orig = obj[method];
   obj[method] = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
     return wrapper.call(this, function(){
       return orig.apply(obj, args);
     }, args);
   }
  return obj[method];
  }
  function intersects(range) {
   return editor.getSelectionRange().intersects(range);
  }
  function preventReadonly(next, args) {
    if (intersects(range)) return;
    next();
   }
```

But I was not able to select the variables to readyOnly.
Could someone help me here, please?

Answer (score 2):

The following is a non-straight forward answer. Here, we are going to validate the entire JSON object, each time you update it.

Implement a function called `isValid`. This is to make sure the keys `number` and `text` are always present.

```
function isValid(code) {
    return (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(code, 'number') &&
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(code, 'text'));
}
```

Implement a function called `updateCode`, which will be triggered during the `onChange`, (and|or something similar to that such as `onPaste`) of the editor

```
function updateCode(code) {
    if (isValid(code)) {
        // UPDATE THE CONTENT TO EDITOR
    } else {
        // AN ERROR MESSAGE MAYBE :)
    }
}
```

Since `hasOwnProperty` checks in a JSON object, make sure you pass a `JSON.parse()`ed `code` and stop the execution if the JSON parsing is a failure. The following function should be triggered during the `onChange` of the Ace editor

```
handleOnChange(code) {
    try {
        var validCodeJson = JSON.parse(code);
        // Valid JSON
        // But Validate keys and update if the object is valid
        updateCode(validCodeJson);
    } catch {
        // Invalid JSON. Don't update
    }
}
```